# Отображение товара в битриксе при интеграции в 1с битрикс

Tags: php, html, битрикс

Нужна ваша помощь профессионалы. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

[image: СЕЙЧАС ОТОБРАЖАЕТСЯ ТАК]

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>

  <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
    <p>
      <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
    </p>
    <?endif?>


      <div class="col-lg-3 card mb-4">
        <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arElement):?>
          <!-- Card -->

          <!--Card image-->
          <div class="card-img">
            <div class="card-img__header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="card-like"></div>
              <div class="card-hit active">хит продаж</div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-img__product">
              <img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/21.png" alt="Card image cap">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--Card content-->
          <div class="card-body">
            <!--Title-->
            <a href="<?=$arElement[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>">
              <h4 class="card-title"><b><?=$arElement["NAME"]?></h4></a>
         <?foreach($arElement["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>
         <div class="card-text">
          <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]))
           echo implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);
           elseif($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"] === true)
           echo "&nbsp;";
           else
           echo $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
                   
          <p>материал: саше</p>
          <p>вес/объем: 10 мл</p>
          <p>упаковка: 500 штук</p>
         </div>
         <?endforeach?>
         <?foreach($arResult["PRICES"] as $code=>$arPrice):?>
         <div class="card-price d-flex align-items-center">
          <?if($arPrice = $arElement["PRICES"][$code]):?>
          <?if($arPrice["DISCOUNT_VALUE"] < $arPrice["VALUE"]):?>
          <p>от </p>
          <?else:?>
          <h4 class="cprice"><b><?=$arPrice["PRINT_VALUE"]?></b></h4>
              <?endif?>
                <?else:?>
                  &nbsp;
                  <?endif;?>
                    <p>руб.</p>
                    <p>упаковка</p>
                    <div id="card-question" data-description="Количество товара Вы всегда можете отредактировать в корзине. Окончательная стоимость товара после обработки заказа менеджером"><img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/product-info-icon.png" alt="question"></div>
          </div>
          <?endforeach;?>
            <?if(count($arResult["PRICES"]) > 0):?>

              <?if($arElement["CAN_BUY"]):?>
                <button href="<?echo $arElement[" BUY_URL "]?>" type="button" class="card-btn d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/cart-white-icon.png" alt="trash">
          <p><?echo GetMessage("CATALOG_BUY")?></p>
         </button>
                <?elseif((count($arResult["PRICES"]) > 0) || is_array($arElement["PRICE_MATRIX"])):?>
                  <?endif?>

                    <p class="bay-hover"><a href="#"><b>Купить в 1 клик</b></a></p>
                    <?endif;?>
      </div>

      <!-- / Card -->
      <?endforeach;?>
        </div>
        <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
          <p>
            <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
          </p>
          <?endif?>
```

Два товара отображает в одной колонке. Причем при большем количества товаров, так же устанавливаются в одной колонке не прерываясь.

Comment: Причем так же при вставке html кодом, отображается так же блоком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказывается была очень проста в решении. Нужно было указать верстку в цикле foreach.

В итоге получился такой. Сам проблему создал, сам же её и решил спустя 4 часа.

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
    /** @var array $arParams */
    /** @var array $arResult */
    /** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
    /** @global CUser $USER */
    /** @global CDatabase $DB */
    /** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
    /** @var string $templateName */
    /** @var string $templateFile */
    /** @var string $templateFolder */
    /** @var string $componentPath */
    /** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
    $this->setFrameMode(true);
    ?>

      <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER"]):?>
        <p>
          <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
        </p>
        <?endif?>


          
            <?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arElement):?>
              <!-- Card -->
<div class="col-lg-3 card mb-4">
              <!--Card image-->
              <div class="card-img">
                <div class="card-img__header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <div class="card-like"></div>
                  <div class="card-hit active">хит продаж</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-img__product">
                  <img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/21.png" alt="Card image cap">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--Card content-->
              <div class="card-body">
                <!--Title-->
                <a href="<?=$arElement[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>">
                  <h4 class="card-title"><b><?=$arElement["NAME"]?></h4></a>
             <?foreach($arElement["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $pid=>$arProperty):?>
             <div class="card-text">
              <?if(is_array($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]))
               echo implode("&nbsp;/&nbsp;", $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"]);
               elseif($arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"] === true)
               echo "&nbsp;";
               else
               echo $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"];?>
                       
              <p>материал: саше</p>
              <p>вес/объем: 10 мл</p>
              <p>упаковка: 500 штук</p>
             </div>
             <?endforeach?>
             <?foreach($arResult["PRICES"] as $code=>$arPrice):?>
             <div class="card-price d-flex align-items-center">
              <?if($arPrice = $arElement["PRICES"][$code]):?>
              <?if($arPrice["DISCOUNT_VALUE"] < $arPrice["VALUE"]):?>
              <p>от </p>
              <?else:?>
              <h4 class="cprice"><b><?=$arPrice["PRINT_VALUE"]?></b></h4>
                  <?endif?>
                    <?else:?>
                      &nbsp;
                      <?endif;?>
                        <p>руб.</p>
                        <p>упаковка</p>
                        <div id="card-question" data-description="Количество товара Вы всегда можете отредактировать в корзине. Окончательная стоимость товара после обработки заказа менеджером"><img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/product-info-icon.png" alt="question"></div>
              </div>
              <?endforeach;?>
                <?if(count($arResult["PRICES"]) > 0):?>

                  <?if($arElement["CAN_BUY"]):?>
                    <button href="<?echo $arElement[" BUY_URL "]?>" type="button" class="card-btn d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <img src="/bitrix/templates/.default/img/cart-white-icon.png" alt="trash">
              <p><?echo GetMessage("CATALOG_BUY")?></p>
             </button>
                    <?elseif((count($arResult["PRICES"]) > 0) || is_array($arElement["PRICE_MATRIX"])):?>
                      <?endif?>

                        <p class="bay-hover"><a href="#"><b>Купить в 1 клик</b></a></p>
                        <?endif;?>
          </div>
</div>
          <!-- / Card -->
          <?endforeach;?>
            
            <?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
              <p>
                <?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
              </p>
              <?endif?>
```

Comment: Вот вы сами через неделю поймете что __конкретно__ вы изменили в этой простыне? А кто ваш ответ будет смотреть вообще без понимания ситуации, ему каково будет?